# How long can we store honey in the home?

Tags: honey

Sometimes honey changes its colour; can this affect its taste? How long can I store honey in my home kitchen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [beeraw.com](http://blog.beeraw.com/real-raw-honey-crystal):

> Honey is a highly concentrated sugar solution. It contains more than 70% sugars and less than 20% water. its means that the water in honey contains more sugar than it should naturally hold. The overabundance of sugar makes honey unstable and crystallize. Thus, it is natural for honey to crystallize.

From [Iowa State University](https://blogs.extension.iastate.edu/answerline/2015/07/30/if-my-honey-has-darkened-is-it-still-safe-to-eat/):

> Over time the honey will darken and flavor will change but it will be safe to eat. [...] As it darkens, it may lose some flavor or become crystals. Resist the urge to use boiling hot water to melt crystals as this can damage the color and flavor of the honey

but still is it safe to use that honey.

Honey jars are stamped with "best before date" that suggests life of 3 years, or even up to 5 years.